# How can I set the minimum order value included tax

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I configured a minimum order value of 15€ in the magento backend, but it seems that this value is not involve the tax, so if I add a product to the cart which costs 17€ I get the message that the minimum order value is not reached :(.

How can I fix this, so that the minimum order value containing the tax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some quick debugging grepping for the `sys/conf` path ending up in the `CartController` that refers to the `Quote` model method `validateMinimumAmount`.

I'm guessing you're not using multishipping so this part of the code calculates whether the amount is enough to be ordered.

```
$baseTotal = 0;
foreach ($addresses as $address) {
    /* @var $address Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address */
    $baseTotal += $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount();
}
if ($baseTotal < $minAmount) {
    return false;
}
```

It uses the `subtotal` to verify the minimum order amount theoretically if you set the sub total of a quote to <strike>exclude</strike> include tax it should fix the issue. Didn't test it so you might need to tweak a bit with the settings.

If all else fails you can always overwrite that part of code to fit your needs.
[Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/how_to_override_magento_model_classes/) has a nice article on overwriting models

Edit:
To further clarify:

- The *base* totals are the totals given in the shop's currency. The final totals (without base prepended) are converted to the customer's currency.
- The *WithDiscount()* part includes catalog rule promotions and discounts configured on the product level. It specifically does **not** include checkout discounts (often referred to as cart discounts, which is an unfortunate choice of words if you ever tried to reflect those discounts in a mini-cart).

Comment: If I add an article to my cart, the cart looks as follows: Subtotal: 17,50 € 
incl. Tax: 2,79 €
Total: 17,50 €

But the minimum order amount message still says the that the minimum order amount is not reached.

Comment: So I have to overwrite this part?

Comment: Yes, thats correct

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the model `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address` and override the method `validateMinimumAmount`:

```
<?php

class StackExchange_MinimumOrderValue_Model_Quote_Address extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address
{

    /**
     * Validate minimum amount
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateMinimumAmount()
    {
        $storeId = $this->getQuote()->getStoreId();
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('sales/minimum_order/active', $storeId)) {
            return true;
        }

        if ($this->getQuote()->getIsVirtual() && $this->getAddressType() == self::TYPE_SHIPPING) {
            return true;
        } elseif (!$this->getQuote()->getIsVirtual() && $this->getAddressType() != self::TYPE_SHIPPING) {
            return true;
        }

        $amount = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/amount', $storeId);
        // $this->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() is sometimes null, so that we calculate it ourselves
        $referenceAmount = $this->getBaseSubtotal() + $this->getBaseTaxAmount() + $this->getBaseHiddenTaxAmount() - $this->getBaseShippingTaxAmount() - abs($this->getBaseDiscountAmount());
        if ($referenceAmount < $amount) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

The interesting thing is that `$this->getBaseSubtotalInclTax()` does not work. It is sometimes `null` - specifically, if you proceed from the cart to the checkout page. Hence, we calculate the subtotal inclusive tax ourselves. I hope my formula is correct, but it seems to work:

```
$referenceAmount = $this->getBaseSubtotal() + $this->getBaseTaxAmount() + $this->getBaseHiddenTaxAmount() - $this->getBaseShippingTaxAmount() - abs($this->getBaseDiscountAmount());
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to rewrite modules. Just type down the value excluding sales tax in the back-end. After that enter a custom message in the display message field. For example if you have 21% sales tax:

- write a minimum order value of €12.40 in the back-end.
- write the following message in the display message field: minimum order amount is €15.00