# Magento : Minimum Grandtotal Amount

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, orders, grand-total

Can I set minimum grandtotal amount to $1 so customer cannot checkout if the grand total is less than $1.

Suppose the subtotal is $5 and customer applied any promo code and get 4.50 as discount and now the grand total is $.50.

But we want to restrict so they cannot do checkout, even not with paypal or any payment gateway.

Comment: you should check [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/53576/20064)

Comment: sales_order_place_before this event suites for you. Write a custom observer for this and try to prevent by redirecting to cart page to add more products.